# Enum index for datagridview event

Tags: c#, datagridview, enums, indexing, switch-statement

In C# I am using enums and add them in a list as strings. I bind the list with a datagridview. In datagridview event I want to click cell and do an action.

How will I do that with the enum as index and NOT the rows?

```
public enum QSystems { WindowsSystem, systemCheck, QDependencies }
_items = new List<string>();
_items.Add(QSystems.WindowsSystem.ToString());
_items.Add(QSystems.systemCheck.ToString());
_items.Add(QSystems.QDependencies.ToString());
```

and in datagridview

```
private void dataGridView2_CellMouseDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
    _ckecklist = new List<FileStatus>();

    switch (e.RowIndex) //this is wrong
    {
        case (short)QSystems.WindowsSystem:
            _ckecklist.Clear();
            ShowSystemStatus();
            dataGridView1.DataSource = _ckecklist;
            SetDatagriDview();
            dataGridView1.Show();
            break;

        case (short)QSystems.systemCheck:
            _ckecklist.Clear();   
            ShowNStatus();
            dataGridView1.DataSource = _ckecklist;
            SetDatagriDview();
            dataGridView1.Show();
            break;

        case (short)QSystems.QDependencies:
            _ckecklist.Clear();
            ShowQDependencies();
            dataGridView1.DataSource = _ckecklist;
            SetDatagriDview();
            dataGridView1.Show();
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can take the string that was selected and convert it to the enum value using parse, example:

```
Colors colorValue = (Colors) Enum.Parse(typeof(Colors), colorString);
```

Another example:

```
String WhatDayItIs = DayOfWeek.Monday.ToString();     

DayOfWeek WhatDayItIsDOW;

if (Enum.IsDefined(typeof(DayOfWeek), WhatDayItIs)) 
        WhatDayItIsDOW = (DayOfWeek)Enum.Parse(typeof(DayOfWeek), WhatDayItIs);
```

Comment: So: switch ((QSystems)Enum.Parse(typeof(Qfit4Systems), (string)) and case (string)QSystems.WindowsSystem: you mean something like this? Thank you in advance

Comment: Yes, something like that.  I added another example to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I solve it with

```
_items = Enum.GetValues(typeof(QSystems)).Cast<QSystems>().ToList();
```

and

```
dataGridView2.DataSource = _items.Select(x => new { Value = x }).ToList();
```

with this the switch state is woking :)